# Get result from controller on submit with tab system in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, tabbing

I Have a form with 2 tabs, this 2 tabs have 2 selections to get the result so if i use form open tabs are not working so can anyone help me to fix the issue without changing url how can i filter my result for different tabs in single form And this is my view file

```
<ul id="myTab2" class="nav nav-tabs sidebar-tabs">
<li class="active">
<a href="#myTab2_example1" data-toggle="tab">
All Merchant IDs
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#myTab2_example2" data-toggle="tab">
Single Merchant ID
</a>
</li>
<li>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="myTab2_example1">
<div class="search_block">
    <div class="form-group mar-b0">
      <div class="section colm colm4">
 <label class="tp-label">Select a year</label>
<select name="transactionYear" id="transactionYear" aria-required="true"   required="required">
<?php $year=$this->livemerchant_model->Year_dropdown();                               
  foreach ($year as $row){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row->TheYear ?>"><?php echo $row->TheYear ?>   </option>
   <?php }?>
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" name="reqsub" id="reqsub" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
</div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Month</th>
  <th>GBP</th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <?php 
  foreach ($monthlyTotals as $row) {?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row->TheMonthName . PHP_EOL;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->TotalAmount. PHP_EOL;?></td>
 </tr>
  <?php }?>
 </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
  </table>
  </div>                                                              
  <?php //echo    form_open_multipart(base_url().'index.php/AdminController/sample');?>
 <div class="search_block">
 <div class="form-group mar-b0">
  <div class="section colm colm4">
  <label class="tp-label">Merchant ID</label>
  <select name="transactionMerchant" id="transactionMerchant" aria-    required="true" required="required">
  <?php $merchanttype = $this->livemerchant_model- >merchant_type_dropdown(); 
 foreach ($merchanttype as $merchant){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $merchant->TRANS_MerchantId ?>"><?php echo   $merchant->TRANS_MerchantId ?></option>
  <?php }?>
 </select>
 <select name="transactionYear" id="transactionYear" aria-required="true" required="required">
 <?php $year=$this->livemerchant_model->Year_dropdown(); 
   foreach ($year as $row){
 ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row->TheYear ?>"><?php echo $row->TheYear ?></option>
  <?php }?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="tell" id="tell" >
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered">                                                              
 <thead>  <tr>                                                              
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>GBP</th>   </tr>                                                                       
 </thead>                                                                                                                                           
 <tbody>                                                                            
 <?php foreach ($monthlyTotals as $row) {?>                                                                     
 <tr>                                                                  
  <td><?php echo $row->TheMonthName . PHP_EOL;  ?> 
   <td><?php echo $row->TotalAmount. PHP_EOL;?></td>                                                                        
  </tr>   
  <?php }?>                                                                       
  </tbody>                                                                      
  <tfoot>  
  </tfoot>
  </table>
  </div>
```

And this is my controller

```
public function overviews()
{

$data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model->overviews();
if ($this->input->post('transactionMerchant,transactionYear')) {
    $data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model->overviews($this->input->post('transactionMerchant'), $this->input->post('transactionYear'));
} else {
    $data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model->overviews();
}


$this->load->view('overviews', $data);
}
```

Could any one help me to resolve the tabbing issue

Comment: can you please make it more clear what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i have 2 submit buttons in one form so can i submit the buttons without changing the url

Comment: You need to use ajax for sending data without reloading/ changing the url

Comment: Thanks @Dray, actually i am new to codeigniter and ajax can i have any coding example

Comment: Well you can find sample code if you Google it, if you still don't find it I will write a sample code for you as soon as I get some time free.